# Wrap choice-field in multiple columns SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, choice-field

Can someone share a function or a method to wrap the choice-field into any given number of columns? Say you have a choice-field of “Checkbox” or “Radio” type with 20 choices and want to arrange them in multiple columns or horizontally instead of vertically.

I tried a code from [this post](https://spjsblog.com/2009/08/19/wrap-choice-field-in-multiple-columns/), but doesnt work for SP2016.

Thanks and Regards,
Himankini

Answer (score 0):

Try using below code in content editor /script editor web part on list form(Not tested):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    $j(document).ready(function()
    {
        var firstRadio = $j(".ms-RadioText:eq(0)");
        $j(".ms-RadioText:gt(0)").appendTo($j(firstRadio));
    });
</script>
```

**Reference**:

1. [Sharepoint choice field (radio button) is displaying vertically](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/257881/wrap-choice-field-in-multiple-columns-SharePoint-2016)

Comment: Have you tried this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this JS code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var reBuildTR = $('<tr></tr>').append("<th></th>");
        //update RadioField as your field name
        $('table[id^="RadioField"]').find('td').each(function () {
            $(reBuildTR).append($(this));
        })
        $('table[id^="RadioField"]').html("").append(reBuildTR);
    })
</script>
```

Just add the display name of your choice field instead of "RadioField" at the line `$('table[id^="RadioField"]')`